# SwiftUI TapGesture and LongPressGesture in ScrollView with tap indication not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm struggling to implement `TapGesture` and `LongPressGesture` simultaneously in a `ScrollView`. Everything works fine with `.onTapGesture` and `.onLongPressGesture`, but I want that the opacity of the button gets reduced when the user taps on it, like a normal `Button()`.

However, a `Button()` doesn't have an option to do something on a long press for whatever reason. So I tried to use `.gesture(LongPressGesture() ... )`. This approach works and shows the tap indication. Unfortunately, that doesn't work with a `ScrollView`: you can't scroll it anymore!

So I did some research and I found out that there has to be a TapGesture before the `LongPressGesture` so `ScrollView` works properly. That's the case indeed but then my `LongPressGesture` doesn't work anymore.

Hope somebody has a solution...

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal){
            HStack{
                ForEach(0..<5){ _ in
                    Button()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Button: View{
    
    @GestureState var isDetectingLongPress = false
    @State var completedLongPress = false
    
    var body: some View{
        
        Circle()
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .opacity(self.isDetectingLongPress ? 0 : 1)
            
            // That works, but there is no indication for the user that the UI recognized the gesture
            //                        .onTapGesture {
            //                            print("Tapped!")
            //                       }
            //                        .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.5){
            //                            print("Long pressed!")
            //                        }
            
            
            // The approach (*) shows the press indication, but the ScrollView is stuck because there is no TapGesture
            
            // If I add a dummy TapGesture, the LongPressGesture won't work anymore but now the ScrollView works as expected
            //.onTapGesture {}
            
            // (*)
            .gesture(LongPressGesture()
                .updating(self.$isDetectingLongPress) { currentstate, gestureState,
                    transaction in
                    gestureState = currentstate
            }
            .onEnded { finished in
                self.completedLongPress = finished
                }
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've tried many combinations of trying onTapGesture + LongPressGesture + custom timings and animations and many work /almost/ but leave minor annoyances. This is what I found that works perfectly. Tested on iOS 13.6.

With this solution your scroll view still scrolls, you get the button depression animation, long pressing on the button works too.

```
struct MainView: View {
    ...
    Scrollview {
        RowView().highPriorityGesture(TapGesture()
                                        .onEnded { _ in
            // The function you would expect to call in a button tap here.
        })
        
    }
}

struct RowView: View {
    
    @State var longPress = false
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            if (self.longPress) {
                self.longPress.toggle()
            } else {
                // Normal button code here
            }
        }) {
            // Buttons LaF here
        }
        // RowView code here.
        .simultaneousGesture(LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.5)
                                .onEnded { _ in
            self.longPress = true
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Nice solution! Works for me as well :)

Comment: How about if the item is in a ScrollView and you want the item to have a LongTap feature as well... that seems to be something that apple can not figure out as it is still outstanding!?

Comment: @Learn2Code if you swap the placement of the .simultaneosGesture and .highPriorityGesture then it will work with two of the same gesture

Comment: Having to wait 500ms for the shrink to happen is not very perfect.